# Touchpad Gestures from fresh installation not the ones expected. Help!

Tags: touchpad, 23.04

Fresh installation of Ubuntu 23.04 on a tablet with a keyboard+trackpad.
Right from the start, on the touchpad, the three-fingers swipe up does not open Activities. The three-fingers tap does.

I am confused, this is a fresh installation of Ubuntu, I should be getting the default Gnome behavior, right?

Is there any file I can go tinked with to fix that?

Thanks for the help.